# `shared_ptr` breaks constness of the object

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, shared-ptr

Consider the following code:

```
class B 
{
    int x;
public:
    B() : x( 10 ) {}
    int get_x() const { return x; }
    void set_x( int value ) { x = value; }
};

class A
{
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b_;
public:
    boost::shared_ptr<B> get_b() const { return b_; } // (1)
};

void f( const A& a)
{
    boost::shared_ptr<B> b = a.get_b();
    int x = b->get_x();
    b->set_x( ++x ); // (2)
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    f( a );

    return 0;
}
```

In this code (2) compiles without any errors or warnings independently the fact that `get_b` is a const function and `a` is a const object.

My question is how do you deal with this situation? The best I could use is to change (1) to the following:

```
boost::shared_ptr<const B> get_b() const { return b_; } // (1)
```

But I should always remember that I should add `const` to the return type. That's not very convenient. Is there a better way?

Comment: The reason that there isn't a better way, is that the C++ language doesn't know that you don't want the instance of `B` to be modified through a `const` instance of `A`. I suppose in theory there could be a syntax for marking that a data member that performs indirection should carry const through that indirection. `shared_ptr` would probably then have to participate in this syntax by telling the compiler how to do that (change the template type from `B` to `const B`), so that the compiler could know what type to convert `b_` to in `const` member functions of A. There is no such syntax.

Comment: If there were such a syntax, then we could all stop asking "what's the best way to write a `const` and a non-`const` getter without duplicating code?" ;-)

Comment: Added `c++0x` tag, is there any solution in the new standard?

Comment: Nope, there unfortunately is not

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This doesn't actually have anything to do with shared pointers per se. I mean if you had a plain pointer you'd have exactly the same problem and would solve it in exactly the same way, that is

```
const B* get_b() const {return b_; }
```

If you left it like

```
B* get_b() const {return b_; }
```

you'd have the same problem.

Well, you have found the solution yourself.

```
boost::shared_ptr<const B> get_b() const { return b_; } // (1)
```

It's the only const-correct way to do it.

Comment: Well, if you call a non-const method on a member variable that is a raw pointer inside a const method, there will be a compile error. Do the same on a shared_ptr, it compiles.